# Uniform convergence of series on interval

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Hey I am supposed to calculate the uniform convergence of series on interval $\left [ -\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2} \right ]$ of:

$$f_n\left ( x \right )=\frac{\sin x+3n}{\sin x}$$

What I did was, that I calculated the limit:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \propto }\frac{\sin x+3n}{\sin x} =0$$ and then I was trying to use supreme criterion:

$$\sigma _{_{n}}=\left | \frac{\sin x+3n}{\sin x}-0 \right |=\sigma _{_{n}}\left | \frac{\sin x+3n}{\sin x} \right |$$ and then I did the derivation of $\frac{\sin x+3n}{\sin x}$: $$\frac{3n\cos x}{\left ( 3n+\sin x \right )^{2}}$$ and find out that stationary point is $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$ but I do not know if it is correct, or what should I do next. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Firstly, $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\sin x + 3n}{\sin x} \rightarrow \infty$. Therefore, your sequence of functions is not convergent.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Is it not 0.bounded function?

Comment: As $n$ increases, for any fixed $x \in \left[ - \dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right]$, the value of $f_n \left( x \right)$ keeps on increasing as a result of which the sequence becomes unbounded and hence not convergent.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh and if I send limit to −π/2 or π/2 ?

Comment: Well, you have to take limits for $n$ and not for $x$. Keeping $x$ fixed, you have to look at what the real valued sequence $f_n \left( x \right)$ looks like and study its convergence. If this sequence is not convergent, you cannot talk about the convergence of the sequence of functions.